# Choosing vector source format for geospatial dashboard

Tags: shapefile, geojson, vector, well-known-text, gml

I'm currently working on a Geospatial dashboard application where I have base maps and raster data in polar-centric projections, using open source tools (GDAL, PostGIS, OpenLayers).

In past projects, I've used GeoJSON for working with vector data and it has been sufficient. However, I have been advised by a colleague that GeoJSON may not be the best choice, as it does not natively support projections other than EPSG 4326. My GeoTIFF raster data is in a different projection and I need to perform calculations using using its intersection with the vector data. I also **need to support circular user-defined vectors**, which I have read is not possible with GeoJSON (https://macwright.com/2015/03/23/geojson-second-bite.html). I'm looking into alternatives (WKT, KML, GML, MVT) but I'm not sure what's the most appropriate for my use case. My input data is in shapefile format, likely to be loaded in to a PostGIS database.

What are my choices when it comes to vector file formats? What benefits do some formats have over others?

Comment: It may sound old-fashioned, but probably GML is the format that supports best both the non-linear geometries and all coordinate reference systems that exist.

Comment: A term I would use to look for your options is “true curves”